# Why my rotation speed sometimes fast sometimes slow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rotate an object with Marhf.PingPong but sometimes it's too fast, sometimes too slow.

`

```
    private void Hit(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.started)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotatingSword());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RotatingSword()
    {     
        do
        {
            t = Mathf.PingPong(Time.Time * rotationSpeed, 1);
            Debug.Log(t);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,defaultRot),
                                                  Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,defaultRot - rotateAngle),t);

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        while (t > 0.1f);
    }
```

`

I tried with the rotation speed first, but it only stayed at 1.Then I try with Time.Fixedtime but it still didn't work.

Comment: Based on the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html): "PingPong returns a value that will increment and decrement between the value 0 and length" it's doing exactly what you don't want. What is the intended result?

Comment: It's not working properly sometimes the rotation takes 1 second sometimes 2

Comment: Does it depend on the angle direction between two positions?